# Laravel 5.2 queue job keeps on retrying

Tags: php, laravel, redis, laravel-5

```
class ProcessComment extends Job implements ShouldQueue
{
    use InteractsWithQueue;

    /**
     * @var int
     */
    public $tries = 1;


    public function handle(Somedepency $someDependency) {
         // method body....
         // tries to connect to a database
         // deliberately provide the wrong database url so that the job .  
         // will throw exception and hence faild
    }
```

The problem is that when i run `php artisan queue:work --daemon` or `php artisan queue:work --daemon --tries=1`

The `tries` option doesn't seem to work. In my redis queue I continuously see the attempts it tries to make like. It should try only one time and if the job failed, just ignore that job and move ahead.

```
"EXEC"
1522044746.165780 [0 172.20.0.5:48992] "WATCH" "queues:comments:reserved"
1522044746.166110 [0 172.20.0.5:48992] "ZRANGEBYSCORE" "queues:comments:reserved" "-inf" "1522044746"
1522044746.166718 [0 172.20.0.5:48992] "UNWATCH"
1522044746.167436 [0 172.20.0.5:48992] "LPOP" "queues:comments"
1522044746.168051 [0 172.20.0.5:48992] "ZADD" "queues:comments:reserved" "1522044806" {"some serialized data here ... "attempts: 4"}
```

and so on

This is my configs/queue.php

```
'default' => env('QUEUE_DRIVER', 'redis'),

    'connections' => [

        'redis' => [
            'driver' => 'redis',
            'connection' => 'default',
            'queue' => 'comments'
        ],
    ],
```

tried to google it alot but couldn't find satisfactory answer.

Thanks

Comment: nothing in the `logs`?

Comment: The log says about the exception of unable to connect to database and this logs keeps on increasing as the job is running again and again.

Comment: So you have your answer

Comment: What do you mean ? The idea is thats the behaviour i want to be. I am purposely trying to connect to wrong database so that the exception will be thrown. What i want is, when the exception is thrown, It means that the job is failing. And i want to make `$tries` to work as expected. It should not keep retrying unlimited times.